# calculate the average of two consecutive rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

say I have the following df:

| Location | Class | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 2 | WD |
| 1 | A2 | 4 | WD |
| 1 | B | 10 | WD |
| 1 | A1 | 4 | WE |
| 1 | A2 | 6 | WE |
| 1 | B | 20 | WE |
| 2 | A1 | 4 | WD |
| 2 | A2 | 6 | WD |
| 2 | B | 15 | WD |
| 2 | A1 | 6 | WE |
| 2 | A2 | 8 | WE |
| 2 | B | 25 | WE |

and I want to cal the average of A1 and A2 at each location and for each type as follows:

| Location | Class | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A12 | 3 | WD |
| 1 | B | 10 | WD |
| 1 | A12 | 5 | WE |
| 1 | B | 20 | WE |
| 2 | A12 | 5 | WD |
| 2 | B | 15 | WD |
| 2 | A12 | 7 | WE |
| 2 | B | 25 | WE |

I have solved this issue by making two different dfs and joining them but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward solution I can use

```
a_list=['A1','A2']
df1=df.loc[df['Class'].isin(a_list)]
df1=df1.groupby(['Location','Type'], as_index = False).agg({'Value':np.sum })

df2=df.loc[df['Class']=='B']

df3=[df1,df2]
df4=pd.concat(df3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.loc[df["Class"].isin(['A1', 'A2']), "Class"] = 'A12'
df.groupby(["Location", "Class", "Type"]).mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Where column `Class` contains A, make it `A12', groupby and aggregate as required

```
   df = df.assign(Class =np.where(df['Class'].str.contains('A'), 'A12', df['Class'])).groupby(['Location','Class','Type']).agg('mean').reset_index()

    Location Class Type  Value
0         1   A12   WD      3
1         1   A12   WE      5
2         1     B   WD     10
3         1     B   WE     20
4         2   A12   WD      5
5         2   A12   WE      7
6         2     B   WD     15
7         2     B   WE     25
```